# dlopen() fails loading opensc-pkcs11.so

Tags: dlopen, pkcs#11, opensc

While trying to dlopen the /usr/lib/x86_64-gnu-linux/opensc-pkcs11.so from within an application, I get a "Cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory" for the library.

```
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
```

I followed the instructions on the Wiki
https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Compiling-and-Installing-on-Unix-flavors

and also did a sudo apt-get install opensc-pkcs11.so. 
The file exists in /usr/lib/x86_64-gnu-linux and that is the library search path.

Is there anything else that needs to be done ? Do any env variables need to be set ? The same works for dlopen of the SoftHSM library.

Wanted to point out that when running the pkcs11-tool command line, it works

```
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so -I
Cryptoki version 2.20
Manufacturer     OpenSC (www.opensc-project.org)
Library          Smart card PKCS#11 API (ver 0.0)
No slot with a token was found.
```

So it appears to be when I try the same dlopen within my application, that it fails. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I try the same dlopen within my application, that it fails

The most likely reason for `no such file` is that the `opensc-pkcs11.so` *itself* has a dependency on some other library, and *that* library isn't found.

You can confirm or disprove this with `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so`.

Comment: The pkcs11-tool does the same dlopen that I run from my application. So it should be seeing the same libraries I would imagine.

Comment: @ksoop "imagining" does not get you closer to solution. Running the command I gave you *might*.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work. Bad library naming convention.